# ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined using React and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

```js
const {MongoClient} = require("mongodb")



function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      Example Text
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Im using Mongodb to extract data from my DB and display it in react. However, inmmediately after I import {MongoClient} I recieve "ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined" error. I've seen some stuff about something called cross origin, but i lack the understanding in how to do that. Any help?  Thanks.

My package.json is the following:

```js
{
  "name": "cart_iew",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "mongodb": "^4.1.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.5",
    "node": "^16.6.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use screenshots to add your code to the question. Instead, just copy and paste as text

Comment: And add your `package.json` code as well

Comment: I edited the fomrat to make it better understandable

Comment: Which browsers did you use to test the app?

Comment: Firefox, Chrome and Microsft Edge